# Namespace Not Being Removed From XML Root with DataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, xml, namespaces, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

Does anyone know why the namespace is still being added to the root during datacontractserialization?

**XML**:

```
<Response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Event>
    <Address>
      .
      .
      .
</Response>
```

**Code:**

```
[DataContract(Name = "Response", Namespace = "")]
public class ApiEventResponse
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ApiEvent Event { get; set; }
}

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type, "Response", "");

return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
      using (var xmlw = new XmlTextWriter(writeStream, Encoding))
      {
          xmlw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
          serializer.WriteObject(xmlw, value);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Note that this is just namespace definition that does not seem to be used (at least in the parts of the xml document you pasted). Your elements are actually in the empty namespace.

Comment: If I had a NULL element that would be the case, it would add i:nill="true"

Comment: Then the declaration would be required and used (not necessarily on the root element though).

Answer (score 2):

The XMLSchema-instance namespace appears to be emitted regardless of what data contracts or actual namespaces are used. The XMLSchema-instance namespace prefix isn't actually used in your example, it's just declared.

The serializer is probably just emitting that namespace always in case it later discovers a situation where it needs to reference XMLSchema while serializing your data.